# Initializing objects inside of constructors C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and cannot figure out this error I am getting. I have created a Card class that stores a suit and rank as an unsigned integer. I also have a Maingame class that runs multiple functions. I want to create 5 Card objects inside of my Maingame class, but I am having a problem initializing them. My Card class is as such..

```
class Card
{
public:
    Card(unsigned int s, unsigned int r);
private:
    unsigned int _suit;
    unsigned int _rank;
};
```

And the constructor for Card()

```
Card::Card(unsigned int s, unsigned int r) {
    _suit = s;
    _rank = r;
}
```

Creating a Card object in the Maingame class

```
class Maingame
{
public:
    Maingame();
    void run();
    void out();
private:
    Card card1;
};
```

And the constructor for Maingame

```
Maingame::Maingame() {
    card1(DIAMONDS, THREE);
}
```

This is where I get an error
"call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion to pointer-to-function type"

Comment: `Maingame::Maingame(): card1(DIAMONDS, THREE) { }` to initialized data members. Read more about [member initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) [initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Comment: In the constructor of `MainGame`, `card1` is a member of the object being constructed.   The syntax `card1(DIAMONDS, THREE)` attempts to use `card1` like a function object, for example to call `card1.operator()(DIAMONDS, THREE)` and there is no such `operator()` - hence the error.  To call the constructo, it is better to use an initialiser list `Maingame::Maingame(): card1(DIAMONDS, THREE) { }`.  To do the work in the constructor body (rarely a good idea), you need to construct another `Card`  and assign e.g.  `Maingame::Maingame() {} {card1 = Card(DIAMONDS, THREE);}`

Comment: Incidentally, your code will have triggered more than one error.   You're only looking at the last one.   The first one (to the effect of `Card` not having a default constructor) is also highly relevant (both in terms of you needing to fix it, and in terms of contributing to the problem you asked about).   Get out of the habit of looking at the LAST error message from the compiler - scroll up and look at the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. It seems you are attempting an *initializer list*, this is the syntax

```
Maingame::Maingame() : card1(DIAMONDS, THREE)
{
}
```

If you had more than one item to initialise then you would separate them with commas.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Maingame` class, the `card1` class member is constructed **before** the *body* of the `Maingame()` constructor is entered.  `Maingame()`'s *body* is trying to invoke an `operator()` call on the already-constructed `card1` object, which has no such operator defined, hence the error.

Also, since the `card1` class member is not being initialized *explicitly* in the `Maingame()` constructor's [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), the compiler will default-construct the `card1` class member, which will also fail since `Card` does not have a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) defined.  `Card` has a custom constructor defined that takes in 2 input values, so the compiler-generated default constructor is disabled, and `Card` is not defining a separate default constructor explicitly.

As such, this code:

```
Maingame::Maingame() {
    card1(DIAMONDS, THREE);
}
```

Is acting more like it had been written like this instead:

```
Maingame::Maingame()
    : card1() // <-- fails, no default constructor defined
{
    card1(DIAMONDS, THREE); // <-- fails, no Card::operator() defined
}
```

To solve both problems, you need to explicitly initialize `Maingame`'s `card1` member in the `Maingame()` constructor's [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), which will allow you to pass input values to `card1`'s constructor, eg:

```
Maingame::Maingame()
    : card1(DIAMONDS, THREE)
{
}
```